# MVC - Loading DLL programmactically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection, architecture, plugins

I'm trying to implement a plugable architecture in asp.net MVC. I have based my modules on the following article - http://www.wynia.org/wordpress/2008/12/aspnet-mvc-plugins.

I have a DLL that contains a simple controller, and a view. The view is an embedded resource within the DLL.

The problem I'm having is, if I drop the DLL in the bin directory of my MVC application manually, then everything works perfectly i.e. the assembly loads correctly. But when I copy the DLL from a file upload input box (via a web form) into the bin directoy, I get an error (The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.) when trying to load the assembly.

I use the same DLL, what could the problem be?

Comment: Are you sure the assembly is written correctly on disk? Sounds to me like the uploaded file is not byte-identical to the original assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok solved, the problem was that I was reading in the input stream from Request.Files[0].InputStream and trying to save the stream, where I should've been getting the HttpPostedFile object.

I think there where content headers that were corrupting the DLL.